# Place a background relative to the position of an environment

Tags: tikz-pgf, framed

I am trying to place a background that extends the entire page width and whose height depends on the height of the environment contained. For example, the following code provides something to what I am looking for:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,calc}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}


\newenvironment{test}[1]{%
\def\FrameCommand{\fboxsep=\FrameSep\colorbox{green!15}}%
\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize -\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}

\begin{document}
\begin{test}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibu-
lum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
Nam arcu libero, nonummy eget, consectetuer id, vulputate a, magna. Donec
vehicula augue eu neque. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et ne-
tus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Mauris ut leo. Cras viverra metus
rhoncus sem. Nulla et lectus vestibulum urna fringilla ultrices. Phasellus eu
tellus sit amet tortor gravida placerat. Integer sapien est, iaculis in, pretium
quis, viverra ac, nunc. Praesent eget sem vel leo ultrices bibendum. Aenean
faucibus. Morbi dolor nulla, malesuada eu, pulvinar at, mollis ac, nulla. Cur-
abitur auctor semper nulla. Donec varius orci eget risus. Duis nibh mi, congue
eu, accumsan eleifend, sagittis quis, diam. Duis eget orci sit amet orci dignissim
rutrum.
\end{test}

\end{document}
```

[image]

But of course this frame only extends to the text width. I want to cover the entire margins on both sides while keeping whatever environment within the `\textwidth`. I was thinking of using the `TikZ` or its affiliate the `background` package. I would reall appreciate solutions within the scope of the `framed` package, `mdframed` package, `TikZ` or `background` package.

Comment: Why not `mdframed`?

Comment: @egreg Yeah why not? I would love that as well.

Answer (score 11):

Use `mdframed` and give margins in wide excess, so that this will work even in twosided printing:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}


\newmdenv[skipabove=\topsep,skipbelow=\topsep,
  leftmargin=-10cm,rightmargin=-10cm,
  innerleftmargin=10cm,innerrightmargin=10cm,
  innertopmargin=\fboxsep,innerbottommargin=\fboxsep,
  backgroundcolor=green!15,
  hidealllines=true,
]{test}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[2]

\begin{test}
\lipsum[1]
\end{test}

\lipsum[3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How can you increase the width of the `\FrameCommand` by using the framed package. Just curious. Are there any parameters that can be added to increase it horizontally and vertically?

Comment: @azetina I haven't the slightest idea.

Answer (score 3):

After consulting with the author of the `framed` package, the following code generates the desired result:

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{framed}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newenvironment{test}[1][green!15]{%
\def\FrameCommand##1{%
\setlength\leftmargin{1in+
    \ifodd\value{page}\oddsidemargin\else\evensidemargin\fi}%
    \setlength\rightmargin{\paperwidth-\textwidth-\leftmargin}%
    %
    \hspace{-\leftmargin}%
    \colorbox{#1}{%
    \hspace{-\fboxsep}%
    \hspace{\leftmargin}%
    ##1%
    \hspace{\rightmargin}%
    \hspace{-\fboxsep}%
    }%
    \hspace{-\rightmargin}%
    }
\MakeFramed {\advance\hsize -\width \FrameRestore}}%
{\endMakeFramed}
\begin{document}
\begin{test}
\lipsum[1-2]
\end{test}
\end{document}
```